# Converting this DB Queries to php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Need help to get this two queries in PDO

PHP Code:

```
if($who!="") 
{ 
$sql = "SELECT id, title, itemurl FROM iwbf_vault WHERE uid='".$who."' ORDER BY pudt DESC LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page"; 
}else{ 
$sql = "SELECT id, title, itemurl, uid FROM iwbf_vault ORDER BY pudt DESC LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page"; 
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/pdo we are not a code translation/writing service. **YOU** write the pdo scaffolding, we'll maybe try help fix it.

Comment: then learn about PDO... we don't do homework

Comment: "Need help to get this two queries in PDO"... hmmm, [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would write it this way:

```
// you may have set this earlier
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$values = array();
$sql = "SELECT id, title, itemurl FROM iwbf_vault WHERE true";
if ($who) {
    $sql .= " AND uid = ?";
    $values[] = $who;
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY pudt DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
$values[] = $limit_start;
$values[] = $items_per_page;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Bill nice to see not everyone is here just for critics to people who know less

Comment: Glad to help @Ненад, yes you're right there are *some* people here who seem concerned only with rejecting questions that are less than 100% perfect. But there are *more* people here who want to contribute answers. But unfortunately, it's quick and easy for the former to spew a discouraging comment. It takes more time and effort for us to post a helpful answer. So the unhelpful comments grow disproportionately to the ratio of people who post them. :-)

Comment: +1 @BillKarwin for such mind :)

Answer (score 0):

An Example for you

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', $user, $pass);
$where = '';
if($who) $where .= " WHERE uid = ':who' ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, title, itemurl FROM iwbf_vault '.$where.' ORDER BY pudt DESC LIMIT :limit_start, :items_per_page');
if($who) $sth->bindValue(':who', $who);
$sth->bindValue(':limit_start', $limit_start);
$sth->bindValue(':items_per_page', $items_per_page);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i like people who are really trying to help

Comment: +1 this is another valid way to code this (though I'd write one `if($who)` for both conditional actions). For what it's worth, the data types like PDO::PARAM_INT in bindParam() and bindValue() are mostly ignored by the pdo_mysql driver. Maybe they are more important for other brands of RDBMS.